# Joining across databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two databases - one called 'autp' (with a table called log) and one called 'charp' (with a table called char).

```
db1: autp               
table: log         
    id         
    action     

db2: charp
table: char
    id
    cg
```

I need to inner join the two on `id` to get `cg`, but only those subject to a specific action (`action = 'xyz'`). How do I join across databases? Previously I've had all tables on one database. I've tried

`SELECT autp.log.id ...`

but no luck. (MySQL 6.0) I suspect this is merely a matter of syntax.

Comment: don't forget the owner.   autp.dbo.log.id might work better if it's owned by dbo.   Incidentally, this is horiible naming for your tables and columns...try to avoid using reserved terms for table names (like char and log).  [autp].[dbo].[log].[id] might be how you have to refer to this as.

Comment: @Twelfth You are using SQL Server syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id,a.action,b.cg
from `autp`.`log` a
join `charp`.`char` b
on b.id = a.id WHERE action = 'xyz'
```

Comment: what's with the confusing, unsightly and superfluous identifier quotation (backtick `\``) characters?

Comment: I just put them there waiting for eggyal to write some quite poetic critique  of them P.Yes only char should have backticks but for the sake of symmetry I sinned.

Comment: Even `char` doesn't require them.  See [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html): "*Exception: A word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted even if it is reserved*".